# Files on Desktop keep rearranging after logging out, logging in, or after reboot/shutdown (16.04.1)

Tags: unity, 16.04, icons

I'm currently facing a very strange issue on Ubuntu 16.04.1. It seems that, every time I log off, log back in, shut down, or restart, the icons on my desktop rearrange by alphabetical order. Even after I move the folders, icons, and files to the places I want them to be at, and then log off, they just get arranged by alphabetical order when I log back in again.

I've tried reinstalling Unity and the Ubuntu Desktop to no avail. Either option seems to keep my Unity settings intact (like my launcher--I have it set to the bottom position). I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

The issue persists regardless of my graphics card--I switched to my Nvidia card and checked if the desktop would save its position (the way I set it to be), but it doesn't. What can I do to make Ubuntu remember my positioning of files on the Desktop?

Thank you for your hard work, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed changing ownership (to my user) and permissions (755) to the file

```
.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
```

The file was owned by root, probably for some bad operation like

```
sudo compiz --replace
```

That should be run without sudo permissions since compiz is a user owned process.
Same issue may occur with an improper use of "gksu".

Answer (score 1):

For me that happened while using the standard theme already, but deleting the metadata store helped. I ran the following commands (as root):

```
pkill gvfsd-metadata 
rm -rf .local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my issue, possibly permanently. Not sure yet.

I changed the icons to the places I wanted them to be on the Desktop. After that, I deleted all entries in gvfs-metadata as root (don't know if that makes a difference or not). Then I disabled "Global Dark Theme" in Tweak Tool. And then I changed all theme/icon/font/etc. settings to the default Ubuntu theme, "Adwaita". I logged out (using CTRL+ALT+DEL, if that's significant), and then tried logging back in.

Ubuntu crashed when I tried logging back in, so I had to hold the power button down. This is a pretty normal occurrence for me whenever I change the UI, sadly. Anyway, I started the laptop back up, and tried logging into Ubuntu again. I logged in, and voila! My icons stayed where I'd put them. I switched back to Flatabulous and my custom icons, logged out, and logged back in to see if the changes stuck. And they did! Hooray!

Hopefully this is permanent. I'm really hoping it is. I spent way too much time trying to fix this issue today.